# in MySQL Query how to use count and sum in master-detail tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to produce something like this that groups by each month (and year)  for a given customer all their invoices (count) and a (sum) of the details qty_shipped.

(example output)

```
CUSTOMER_NO , YR,    MO,   COUNT_INVOICES, TOTAL_QTY_SHIPPED
18            2015,  01,   30,             300 
18            2014,  12,   65,             12323
18            2014,  11,   34,             4344
```

I have a simple invoices (master pk:inv_id) table and corresponding invoices-detail (detail fk_inv_id), the detail table is joined to the master by the fk: inv_id. Table structure looks like.

```
MASTER (Invoice)
inv_id
innvoice_number
customer_no
updated

DETAIL (invoices-detail )
invdet_id
inv_id
product_no
qty_shipped
qty_ordered


...
```

I'm trying but it doesn't seem to work.It seems to mis-count the sum of the qty_shipped

```
 SELECT customer_no,YEAR(i.updated) as yr, MONTH(i.updated) as mnth,count(i.inv_id) as  invoices_shipped ,
--subquery--
(SELECT  count(idet.qty_shipped)  
FROM invoice_details idet WHERE idet.inv_id=i.inv_id) as qty_shipped_TOTAL 
--end subquery--
FROM invoice i WHERE status="SHIPPED" AND  customer_no=18 
GROUP BY  YEAR(i.updated) DESC, MONTH(i.updated) DESC;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `JOIN` them together and use `GROUP BY` on the result

Answer (score 0):

Make a join:

```
SELECT 
     i.customer_no,
     YEAR(i.updated) as yr, 
     MONTH(i.updated) as mnth, 
     count(i.inv_id) as  invoices_shipped, 
     sum(idet.qty_shipped) 

FROM invoice i WHERE status="SHIPPED" AND  customer_no=18 

left join invoice_details idet on idet.inv_id=i.inv_id

GROUP BY  i.customer_no, YEAR(i.updated), MONTH(i.updated)

order by YEAR(i.updated) DESC, MONTH(i.updated) DESC;
```